# Styling React Bootstrap Component in Active State

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to style a React Bootstrap Navbar. I was able to successfully style the non-active tabs, however, I cannot seems to reach the active tab.
My styles live is a separate .scss file. Here's the relevant snippet:

```
.navitem {
  a {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-color: #357ebd;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom-width: 2px;
  }
  flex: 1;
}

.navitem.active {
  background-color: #777777;
}
```

When an active Bootstrap component is created, its HTML looks like this:

```
<li role="presentation" class="Preview-navitem--19fA7 active"><a role="button" href="#">Preview</a></li>
```

Here's the HTML inside the react render() method:

```
<Nav
            className={styles.navbar}
            bsStyle="pills"
            activeKey={this.state.value}
            onSelect={this.handleSelect}
          >
            <NavItem className={styles.navitem} eventKey="1">Preview</NavItem>
            {navItem}
</Nav>
```

So, basically, I can style the .navitem, but not the .active.
Any idea how I could accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using CSS Modules or something similar? It looks like your `.navitem` is getting changed to `Preview-navitem--19fA7`, which means your `.navitem.active` is getting changed as well, which is why it isn't matching.

Comment: @JamesGanong, that's bootstrap's doing. `.navitem` does get picked up, but I cannot seem to get it to see the active state.

Comment: Are you adding the `navitem` class to your `NavItem` component? I can't find anywhere in the react-bootstrap code where it's adding that class. I'm fairly certain what's happening is your css processing is modifying your classnames, but the active classname is getting added to your `li` by react-bootstrap, which is outside your processor. So the `active` class is added as `active`, but your css file has a different style name for `.navitem.active`. Can you find in your processed css file what `.navitem.active` is being changed to?

Comment: @JamesGanong The `.navitem.active` doesn't appear when I inspect the code in the browser, so I assume it doesn't get processed. Or it does, but doesn't apply to the active element. I've edited my post to show what I render in the React code.

Comment: Can you look in the CSS file to see what `.navitem.active` is?

Comment: @JamesGanong it doesn't show up when you inspect the page... so I don't know. That's the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this is CSS Modules, which it looks like based on the pasted code, the solution is to use global selectors. CSS Modules briefly mentions this on the main README page under [Exceptions](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#exceptions). However, their [webpack demo](https://github.com/css-modules/webpack-demo) has a [global selector example](https://github.com/css-modules/webpack-demo/tree/master/src/components/2-GlobalSelectors) you can clone and play around with.

In short, you should change:

```
.navitem.active {
  background-color: #777777;
}
```

to:

```
.navitem:global(.active) {
  background-color: #777777;
}
```

in order for it to be processed properly by Webpack. This should be all that's needed!

Comment: Amazing. Thank you SO much for your help!

Comment: for anyone reading this in 2020, this worked for me, but only after adding !important